# How can I add multiple formulas to a long text cell?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell in a Google Sheets doc that is the template HTML for an e-commerce webpage. It's very long as there's lots of content on the webpage, and of course, the whole cell is a text format because HTML is text. I want to be able to have that HTML text look up other cells in the spreadsheet to populate parts of the HTML with values I have typed in other cells. So if my HTML is in cell A1 and in one part of it it says `=B1` (or whatever you end up telling me) I want to be able to type `Apple` in cell B1 and have the HTML text replace `=B1` with `apple`. Is there some way that, within a text format cell you can signify to Sheets "this next bit is a formula"? Basically, what should I type instead of the `=B1` I used above to make this lookup work? Remember this is all in a text cell.

I've tried various ways of doing this but all seem to rely on having the cell in formula format, but this is not possible as I need to do this lookup process many times in a single cell with a large amount of text in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please add a coding snippet featuring your problem and check this article before asking questions : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It looks that are asking about how formulas work in Google Sheets, specifically how formulas handle text values.

In Google Sheets, a formula start with `=` or `+`. As you question is about text values, the you should use `=`.

After the `=` your could add a quote enclosed text like `="apple"`. If your text include quotation marks, then you should escape them. Let say that your text is `"apple"` then the formula to use is `="""apple"""`.

Let's do a jump.

The concatenation operator is `&`. Let say that you have `="""apple"" ""orange"""` on one cell, and `grape` in cell A1. To put a reference to A1 in order to insert it's value between the quoted fruits, the formula to be used is `="""apple""" & A1 & """orange"""`.